# IntelliJ IDEA settings for Scala and Java style

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have one style for Java and one for Scala.
Intellij>Settings>Editor>Code Style allows us to choose just one scheme and this make two different languages (Java and Scala) have one style scheme.
Is there any way to set a code style per language?

I put `scalastyle_config.xml` under the project root/.idea/.
But any Scala style violation does not produce any build error.
FYI, IntelliJ IDEA editor windows show style-violation lines in red but it does not auto-adjust in case of import order violations.

Comment: Please clarify. Code style and code inspections are not related. Also, neither code style nor code inspection would produce a build error. Java and Scala have separate settings pages in the Code Style, so they can have different code styles within the same code style profile (xml).

Comment: I have an organization-wide used java check style and it was chosen in Settings>...>Code Style as a chosen scheme. Recently, I developed a scala check style separately as recommended as in scalastyle.org (scalastyle_config.xml). I put the scala one under <project root>/.idea/ folder. It seems this scalastyle_config.xml works over the chosen java style, for example, import order rule. However, when add a new import line automatically

Comment: (cont.) by IDE, intellij adds the import line based on java import rule. So, I need to manually readjust it. I think this is because intellij uses one single code style scheme. As of now, I don't know how to merge scalastyle_config.xml onto the existing java check style because exported intellij code style scheme is quite different in terms of its format.

Comment: However, your answer about there is no way to produce build errors based on style errors helped me. Thanks!